# How to publish React.js + Redux component

Tags: reactjs, npm, redux

I've created React.js+Redux app that I want to publish as a reusable npm component. But do not know proper way.
Here is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './MyComponent/store';

import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';

function App() {    
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={xxxxxxx}>
          <MyComponent/>
        </ThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I published it then trying to call it from other app.

```
>> npm install my-test-app@0.0.1

import MyComponent from 'my-test-app';
...
<MyComponent />
```

The app starts but seems MyComponent has no access to store and theme provider. my-test-app itself works fine on local.
What would be correct code in App.js so it works in parent app?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to pass store instance as a prop to your app and all underlying dependencies.